# ESLint import/order rule works differently on different machines - error `..` import should occur before import of `.`

Tags: eslint, line-endings

I have an issue where there are some imports

```
import foo from "."; 
import bar from "..";
```

The problem I'm having is that on my machine this will give me the error;

```
error  `..` import should occur before import of `.`  import/order
```

Whereas, on my friend's machine this will look fine, and swapping them around will give the same error but reversed.

If we run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint -v` both show as 4.19.1.

What could likely be going on here to cause eslint to behave differently? Something around whitespace or line endings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug that occurs in differences between `eslint-plugin-import` @ 2.20.1 and 2.20.2.

See: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1760